# insertAfter - find - on() -- not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i think, i have all set, but it is still not working - i am appending new html element `input` with `X` delete sign. if i click on that newly added `X` sign, the newly added input should be deleted. what i did is:

```
function addmore(){
   $('<input type="file" name="bild[]"/> <a class="del">X</a> <br/>').insertAfter('#more').find('.del').on('click', function(){
   alert('test');
   });
 }
```

my html is:

```
 <a href="javascript:addmore()"> add more </a>
 <p id="more"></p>
```

it is inserting well, but i cannot delete the newly added element (alert is not firing). why is this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Change `find` to `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find()` function looks for elements that are *inside* the current set of matched elements, but doesn't include those matched elements. Your `<a class="del">` element is part of the set of matched elements so won't be picked up.

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
....filter('.del').on('click', function() {...});
```

Comment: can you give me pls a little hint on how to delete the input field which is right beside that ``X``. ?

Comment: @doniyor `$(this).prev()` will select the `<input>` element, where `this` inside the `click` event handler function is the `<a>` element you clicked on. Then you can call any jQuery function - such as `.remove()` - on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    function addmore(){
        var element = $('<input type="file" name="bild[]"/> <a class="del">X</a> <br/>').insertAfter('#more');
        element.filter(".del").on('click', function(){
        alert('test');
       });
     }
```

Comment: There's no `jquery` variable defined in that scope - you possibly meant `jQuery`, but you can't call `.on()` on that, you need to select elements first.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.find()` selector doesn't actually return anything. If you look at how jQuery processes your HTML string:

```
> $('<input type="file" name="bild[]"/> <a class="del">X</a> <br/>')
[<input type=​"file" name=​"bild[]​">​, #text, <a class=​"del">​X​</a>​, #text, <br>​]
```

You'll see that it's actually parsing each of those elements and text nodes as separate elements in a selector. `.find()` won't return anything, as it'll look only through the descendants of those elements, not the elements themselves:

```
> $('<input type="file" name="bild[]"/> <a class="del">X</a> <br/>').find('.del')
[]
```

I'd start with something like this:

```
$('<input type="file" name="bild[]"/>').insertAfter('#more');
$('<a class="del">X</a>').insertAfter('#more').on('click', function(){
    alert('test');
});

$('<br/>').insertAfter('#more');
```

Or make a generic selector from the beginning that automatically handles click events, even for elements that don't exist yet:

```
$('#more').on('click', '.del', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: @doniyor: Don't put so much HTML into your JavaScript. Use a template or something.