# TypeError: $(...).find(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typeerror

I have to admin a quite small web presentation with only some javascript. It was written some years ago and now I try to implement a mobile compatible menu.

This are the versions of jQuery which were installed before I started with the new menu:
jQuery.min.js : jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.1
jQuery.tools.overlay.min.js : jQuery Tools v1.2.7 - The missing UI library for the Web
jQuery-ui.min.js : jQuery UI 1.8.13

Now I try several newer jQuery code, and at the moment I use this versions:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1-12-3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

The plug in I want to use for the menu is "doubletaptogo.js":

```
(function($) {

  /*
    Responsive Flat Menu
    http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu
  */

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        } else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          } else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

/*
    By Osvaldas Valutis, www.osvaldas.info
    Available for use under the MIT License
*/

;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  $.fn.doubleTapToGo = function(params) {
    if (!('ontouchstart' in window) &&
      !navigator.msMaxTouchPoints &&
      !navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/windows phone os 7/i)) return false;

    this.each(function() {
      var curItem = false;

      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        var item = $(this);
        if (item[0] != curItem[0]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          curItem = item;
        }
      });

      $(document).on('click touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e) {
        var resetItem = true,
          parents = $(e.target).parents();

        for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++)
          if (parents[i] == curItem[0])
            resetItem = false;

        if (resetItem)
          curItem = false;
      });
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);

/**
 * doubleTapToGoDecorator
 * Adds the ability to remove the need for a second tap
 * when in the mobile view
 *
 * @param {function} f - doubleTapToGo
 */
function doubleTapToGoDecorator(f) {
  return function() {

    this.each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {

        // If mobile menu view
        if ($('#menu-button').css('display') == 'block') {

          // If this is not a submenu button
          if (!$(e.target).hasClass('submenu-button')) {

            // Remove the need for a second tap
            window.location.href = $(e.target).attr('href');
          }
        }

      });
    });

    return f.apply(this);
  }
}

// Add decorator to the doubleTapToGo plugin
jQuery.fn.doubleTapToGo = doubleTapToGoDecorator(jQuery.fn.doubleTapToGo);

/**
 * jQuery
 */
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "Menu",
      format: "multitoggle"
    });

    $('#cssmenu li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();

  });
})(jQuery);
```

The menu looks like:

```
<nav id='cssmenu' role='navigation'>   
    <a href="#cssmenu" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
  <ul>...
```

...and when I debug with Firebug I always see the error mentioned in subject of this post!

Are there still problems with the versions of jQuery? I'm very sorry, but I'm not used to programming very much in javascript.

### Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

I added now

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script> //  v1.11.4
```

I bind the doubletaptogo with that code to the body of my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.cssmenu').doubleTapToGo();
  });
</script>
```

---

So far, it unfortunately does not work.
With this doubletaptogo.min.js I have a fine menu on my Laptop, without an error in Firebug, but no menu on my mobile Units:

```
;(function(e,t,n,r){e.fn.doubleTapToGo=function(r){if(!("ontouchstart"in t)&&!navigator.msMaxTouchPoints&&!navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/windows phone os 7/i))return false;this.each(function(){var t=false;e(this).on("click",function(n){var r=e(this);if(r[0]!=t[0]){n.preventDefault();t=r}});e(n).on("click touchstart MSPointerDown",function(n){var r=true,i=e(n.target).parents();for(var s=0;s<i.length;s++)if(i[s]==t[0])r=false;if(r)t=false})});return this}})(jQuery,window,document);
```

With that doubletaptogo.js there is an error in Firebug (like mentioned in the subject), but a fine menu on my Laptop, and a "Menu" on my mobile Units which does not react on anything. I tried also to Change the find() against a filter(), but then the filter() was "not a function".

What else can be the Problem?
I also tried to use only the code of that site as a menu, just to Show it on my site: 
http://codepen.io/dmitrykiselyov/pen/XJwqZM
...and this did not work also. There was only the "Menu" on my mobile Units which did not react.
So, may be Problem with the jQuery? I use now the jquery-1-12-3.min.js and the ui is Version v1.11.4. 
May be a bad combination?

Comment: I don't know if it's actually required, but doubletaptogo says it needs jquery-ui 1.10 or higher in its bower.json. Have you tried upgrading jQuery UI?

Comment: hmm... now I also added '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>' with version v1.11.4 - 2016-04-25. The error which is displayed now is TypeError: '$(...).doubleTapToGo is not a function
$('.cssmenu').doubleTapToGo();'

Comment: ... what I also included was this  <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('.cssmenu').doubleTapToGo();}); </script>   in the body

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335944/insertafter-find-on-not-working check the link. Hope this solves your prob.

Comment: @csixty4: how do you know that jquery-ui 1.10 or higher is needed for doubletaptogo? I've nowhere read anything about that need!

Comment: I found the library on Github at https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-doubleTapToGo/blob/master/bower.json .  The bower.json file is used for the Bower package manager and there might be reasons for specifying 1.10 or higer besides compatibility. For example, they may use an automated testing setup that only works with version 1.10 or higher, or the author might think that's as far back as they're willing to support. But it's generally a good idea to stick with the supported versions of dependencies.

Comment: Now, after I tried other things which I've mentioned in the main post above, I also tried the code from Github, but I guess there is no correct binding to my page. With that code (also the jQuery from that site) there is that error: `TypeError: $.widget is not a function
jquery....togo.js (Zeile 28)
TypeError: $(...).doubleTapToGo is not a function`   I only have the complete menu on my laptop and on my mobile device, but without css and without the dropdown functionality.

Comment: When I copy the jquery.dcd.doubletaptogo.js and the html code to this page: [http://codepen.io/dmitrykiselyov/pen/XJwqZM]  ...then I see a working menu - but I don't know if it would work on a mobile device also.  So... I'm confused because of all that different codes and different versions of codes I've found during my tests. What else could be the problem?

Comment: What about the bower.json ? Where do I have to include it? So far I didn't..... But could that be the reason for that errors?

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, solution is please use the latest jQuery version from 1.x.y serie (you can pick here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery/ 1.12.4 is working well for me).